# Do you know any saturation function? To make number fit to given range?

Tags: rust, range, saturation-arithmetic

Looking for a saturating function in Rust.
Here I called it *fit_to_range(range)*.

```
  let input:i64= something;
  let saturated:64= input.fit_to_range(7..=4000);
  assert!((7..=4000).contains(saturated));
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you're looking for is the `clamp` function defined in the `Ord` trait, which is implemented by `i64`.
For example:

```rust
let input: i64 = 5000;
let saturated = input.clamp(7, 4000);
assert!((7..=4000).contains(&saturated));
```

[Documentation of the clamp function](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.Ord.html#method.clamp)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `min()` and `max()`.

```rust
  let input: i64 = 8456;
  let saturated: i64 = input.max(7).min(4000);
  assert!((7..=4000).contains(saturated));
```

Comment: I appreciate this method, it is concise, not only in Rust.